# How to get .po files from .mo

Tags: php, translation, gettext

I have a question for you. I have my translations .mo files but I want to get the .po files, is there a way to do this?
My file source is :

```
/ressource
  /translation
    /es_ES.UTF-8
      /LC_MESSAGES
        test.mo
```

I tried :

```
msgunfmt /ressource/translation/mo/es_ES.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/test.mo > /ressource/translation/mo/es_ES.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/test.po but not result
```

Help me please

Answer (score 4):

There are several online tools that do that using `msgfmt`. [Here](http://tools.konstruktors.com/) is one of them.

If you want to do it locally from the terminal just call:

`msgunfmt /ressource/translation/mo/es_ES.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/test.mo`

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed several tools, one of them is [Poedit](http://poedit.net).
It is an install you can use for making .mo and .po files.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Bono To be fair, this is a link to a tool. How does one summarise a tool in an answer?